# Ошибка empty sql statement

Tags: sql, delphi-7, firebird

Использую Delphi7+Firebird1.5.  Cуть в том, что введенные на форме данные отправляются в базу. Вот только этого не случается. Появляется ошибка:

> "Project такой-то raised exception class EIBClientError with message
>   'Empty SQL Statement'."

Созданная для проверки строка **s** заполняется, т.е. **Query** не пуст.    Правда там в конце строки какие-то спецсимволы вставляются (#$A#$D или что-то в этом роде), но наверное так и надо.

```
Form1.IBQuery1.SQL.Clear;
Form1.IBQuery1.SQL.Add('INSERT INTO VLADELCI(FAMILIYA, IMYA, OTCHESTVO,
    DATA_ROJDENIYA, ADRES_REGUSTRACII, TELEFON, EMAIL, PASPORTNIE_DANNIE,
    N_VODITELSKOGO) VALUES (' + QuotedStr(Edit2.Text)+', '+QuotedStr(Edit3.Text)+', '+QuotedStr(Edit4.Text)+', '+QuotedStr(FormatdateTime('dd/mm/yyyy',DateTimePicker1.Date))+', '+QuotedStr(Edit6.Text)+', '+QuotedStr(MaskEdit2.Text)+', '+QuotedStr(Edit9.Text)+', '+QuotedStr(Edit8.Text)+', '+QuotedStr(Edit10.Text)+');');
s:=Form1.IBQuery1.SQL.GetText;
Form1.IBQuery1.ExecSQL;
```

Вот что оказывается в **s**:

```
s: 'INSERT INTO VLADELCI(FAMILIYA, IMYA, OTCHESTVO, DATA_ROJDENIYA,
ADRES_REGUSTRACII, TELEFON, EMAIL, PASPORTNIE_DANNIE, N_VODITELSKOGO) 
VALUES   ('Иванов', 'Иван', 'Иванович', '01.01.1980', 
'Петрозаводск,ул.Ленина,д.1', 
'8(925)763-78-43', 'ivanov@yandex.ru', '4511674523ГУВД503',
'00000000');'#$D#$A
```

Помогите пожалуйста!

ВСЕ! проблема решилась. Извините за беспокойство, всем спасибо, причина была исключительно в моей глупости (ну а разве бывает иначе?=)). Я накидала в форму всех компонентов, какие могли пригодиться на мой вгляд, в итоге у меня был и Query и DataSet, и в итоге обращение к базе шло через DataSet. Удалила его, перепрописала компоненты друг у друга в свойствах и все работает

Comment: Попробуйте убрать точку с запятой в конце запроса. Некоторые SQL-СУБД реагируют на нее так, словно ожидают еще одного запроса.

Comment: *Появляется ошибка* - и мы должны догадаться, какая именно?

Comment: @AlexanderZonov, пробовала, не помогло(

Comment: @Akina, название ошибки в заголовке. Точнее она звучит как "Project такой-то raised exception class EIBClientError with message 'Empty SQL Statement'."

Comment: В таком случае полностью согласен с Александром - уберите точку с запятой. Это первое. И второе - Вы убеждены, что Firebird правильно поймёт тот формат даты (`dd.mm.yyyy`), который получился у Вас?

Comment: похоже, что у вас проблема с квотированием - попробуйте экранировать символы **'** внутри запроса

Comment: `D-A` в конце это `#13#10` возврат каретки, перенос строки. в случае видны - комбинация переноса на новую строку. маловероятно что это может влиять как то, но обычно в используют таки не `sql.add(...)` а `sql.text := ...` но мб в паре с точкой с запятой СУБД и пытается как то разбить новую строку в пустой запрос.

Answer (score 0):

в качестве ремарки, обычно подобный код пишут следующий образом

```
 try
    IBQuery1.SQL.Text :=
            'INSERT INTO VLADELCI ('#13+
                'FAMILIYA, IMYA, OTCHESTVO,'#13+
                'DATA_ROJDENIYA, ADRES_REGUSTRACII,'#13+
                'TELEFON, EMAIL, PASPORTNIE_DANNIE, N_VODITELSKOGO )'#13+
            'VALUES (:surname, :name, :sname, :bd, :address, :phone, :email, :pass, :dlicence)';

    IBQuery1.ParamByName('surname').AsString := Edit2.Text;
    IBQuery1.ParamByName('name').AsString    := Edit3.Text;
    IBQuery1.ParamByName('sname').AsString   := Edit4.Text;
    IBQuery1.ParamByName('bd').AsString      := FormatdateTime('dd/mm/yyyy',DateTimePicker1.Date);
    IBQuery1.ParamByName('address').AsString := Edit6.Text;
    IBQuery1.ParamByName('phone').AsString   := MaskEdit2.Text;
    IBQuery1.ParamByName('email').AsString   := Edit9.Text);
    IBQuery1.ParamByName('pass').AsString    := Edit8.Text);
    IBQuery1.ParamByName('dlicence').AsString:= Edit10.Text);

    IBQuery1.ExecSQL();
except
      on e : Exception do begin
          // что-то пошло не так
      end;
end;
```

Это длиннее выглядит, конечно, но удобнее и безопаснее.
Так же именуйте компоненты нормальным образом. `IBQuery1 -> InsertQuery`, `Edit1 -> SurnameEdit` и т.п.

А вообще там есть компоненты а-ля `TDBEdit`, которые можно привязать к датасету, и установив его в режим `Insert` вставить данные почти без написания кода.